# how to hide bottom bar when typing( keyboard is up) using compose

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose

I made text field for typing.
When soft keyboard is up, I hope to hide bottom bar.
How can I hide it in compose?

```
windowsoftinputmode="adjustpan"
```

I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I am also facing same issue but didn't get any solutions yet. I have a button at bottom bar and it comes up when I open up the keyboard.